# How do I access the Kippt API through Ruby without an external library?

Tags: ruby, api

I want to access the Kippt API through Ruby without the usage of any **external** libraries whatsoever, i.e. everything that comes packed with Ruby is fine, but nothing else (except for the standard library).

How should I go about doing this? Please detail the process.

Comment: Could you clarify "without the usage of any libraries whatsoever"? Taken literally, that would entail implementing low-level TCP/IP, HTTP, JSON-serialisation from scratch. That seems counter-productive, could you at least provide some context on why you think this is necessary, and what you have already tried?

Comment: Does this edit clarify the question somewhat?

Comment: Yes, so Ruby core is obviously ok. Is the standard library? http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/index.html - important because it is where you will find basic JSON and HTTP support.

Comment: As per the edit, the standard library is fine.

Comment: OK, good. And what have you tried, have you got as far as actually making a connection to the API, do you have any existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic access, showing it is possible:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse( 'https://kippt.com/api/users/1/' )
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)

response = http.request(request)

data = JSON.parse( response.body )

 => {
  "username"=>"jorilallo", 
  "bio"=>"Co-founder of Kippt. I love building products.", 
  "app_url"=>"/jorilallo",
  "avatar_url"=>"https://d19weqihs4yh5u.cloudfront.net/avatars/147d86b9-0830-49d8-a449-0421a6a4bf05/160x160", 
  "twitter"=>"jorilallo", 
  "id"=>1, "github"=>"jorde",
  "website_url"=>"http://about.me/jorilallo", 
  "full_name"=>"Jori Lallo", 
  "dribbble"=>"jorilallo", 
  "counts"=>{"follows"=>1192, "followed_by"=>23628}, 
  "is_pro"=>true, "resource_uri"=>"/api/users/1/"
}
```

There is a fair amount of work to take this demonstration and put it into some re-usable code that copes with authentication, posting params, request failure and other standard issues for HTTP-based APIs.

I'd suggest reading http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html for some examples of how to build and process the requests in more detail. That's how I did the above (until writing the answer, I'd never used Ruby's net/http directly before, and I just grabbed a likely looking block of code from that site).